# Protractor angular sync failing, an error from webdriver - ' Cannot read property '$injector' of undefined'

Tags: angular, protractor, webdriver

We have started seeing a very weird issue with protractor angular sync (on an angular page). Some tests started failing with 'Failed: script timeout', protractor not being able to synchronize with Angular. However, there aren't any new setTimeouts, setIntervals or anything in the angular code that could have caused this exact type of issue.

This issue is happening after we turn Angular sync off with waitForAngularEnabled(false), and then turned it back on with waitForAngularEnabled(true) (after which protractor just hangs and cannot sync with angular after this switch).

In the webdriver logs, I see an error being reported: Cannot read property '$injector' of undefined, preceded by the invocation of protractor getNg1Hooks method. Driver log snippet:

```
COMMAND ExecuteScript {
   "args": [ "" ],
   "script": "try { return (function anonymous(\n) {\nfunction getNg1Hooks(selector, injectorPlease) {\n  function tryEl(el) {\n    try {\n      if (!injectorPlease && angular.getTestability) {\n        var $$testabil..."
}
.................................

Done waiting for pending navigations. Status: ok

RESPONSE ExecuteScript unknown error: Cannot read property '$injector' of undefined
  (Session info: chrome=87.0.4280.141)

COMMAND GetLog {
   "type": "browser"
}
```

In the browser logs, and network tab there are no ongoing requests (like something that would make protractor wait).

However, this information was not entirely indicative what has happened- why the browser returned this error to webdriver, causing protractor to time-out. Any ideas what could cause it and what more info I could gather to understand where the issue lies.

The protractor version is 7.0.0, we use webdriver chrome 2.37 (although I did try with the latest compatible - 87.0.4280.14, and it did not help)

Answer (score 0):

Same here. Issue started this week. Needed to revert back to `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false)`.

I guess an issue with the Chrome Driver.

Comment: Which version of chromedriver do you use? I tried upgrading ours, but it still faced this issue

Comment: Mine was 88, So I guess the problem is with 87 and 88 (or it is in another part of the system).